# How many titles did Dumbledore hold?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> (**Order of Merlin, First Class, Grand Sorc.**, Chf. Warlock, Supreme Mugwump, >International Confed. of Wizards)

Is **"Order of Merlin, First Class"** and **"Grand Sorc."** one title or two?

Comment: It is common to use the semicolon to separate items in a list when any of the items in the list contains a comma.  https://writing.wisc.edu/Handbook/Semicolons.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Order of Merlin, First Class" is likely one single title, because "First Class" usually modifies a title or classification  and is not very reasonable on its own.

"Grand Sorcerer" is likely a title by itself, but there is nothing intrinsic in the punctuation, grammar, etc. that makes this distinction explicit. However, it fits with the other items that follow, and it seems unlikely that they are all specifiers of "Order of Merlin" like "First Class".

"International Confederation of Wizards" is the group of which Dumbledore holds the title "Supreme Mugwump", because it would not be a title on its own.

**The most reasonable interpretation of the titles** would be:

> 1. Order of Merlin, First Class
> 2. Grand Sorcerer
> 3. Chief Warlock
> 4. Supreme Mugwump, International Confederation of Wizards

The list would be more clear if semicolons had been used to separate the titles, which is common with the items of a list contain commas themselves. For example:

> (Order of Merlin, First Class; Grand Sorc.; Chf. Warlock; Supreme Mugwump, International Confed. of Wizards)

For future in-universe questions, it would be better to ask on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) (i.e. Is "Grand Sorcerer" a title distinct from "Order of Merlin, First Class" in Harry Potter?)

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to ask. I've searched on Harry Potter Wiki, it's said that  "Grand Sorcerer" might be a single title.So I'm wondering if they are two titles when it followed "Order of Merlin, First Class".

Comment: @狗撸撸 The question can't really be answered based on English grammar or punctuation. If you want an in-universe answer, try scifi.stackexchange.com (although as a HP fan myself, I believe "Grand Sorcerer" is a title by itself).

Comment: Semantically, in English, first class follows another noun. First class is not a title by itself.

Comment: @Lambie Yes, but the real question is whether "Grand Sorcerer" is a specifier of "Order of Merlin" or a title on its own. One can make a reasonable deduction, but there is no explicit answer based on parsing or syntax.

Comment: @Lambie could it be short for the first class owner?

Comment: "Order of Merlin, First Class, Grand Sorc."should be read as a whole sentence,but may have two titles in it, is that right?

Comment: @狗撸撸 I have expanded the answer.

Comment: @狗撸撸 There are no owners here. There is no sentence. What there is, is a list of titles which I gave in my answer and which you seem to have ignored.

Comment: @Tashus I chosen the wrong word, my English is bad. what I try to say is, does "Order of Merlin, First Class" need to follow any other nouns to make sense? Or it just stand itself? I don't know how to make it clear...

Comment: now I understand after reading your answer.

Comment: @狗撸撸 If you like the answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @Tashus Why I couldn't find the link you posted on the homepage of this web? Where is the entrance?

Answer (score 3):

Order of Merlin, First Class, Grand Sorc., Chf. Warlock, Supreme Mugwump

In English, medals are sometimes given more than one designation:

- Order of Merlin, First Class [similar to the British usage of a First Class honours' degree]
- Grand Sorcerer
- Chief Warlock
- Mugwump Supreme.

My analysis is based on what the OP posted. There are, therefore, four titles.

Answer (score -1):

It is a single one. First Class is an adjective that shows this is the best possible rank one can have in the Order of Merlin and Grand Sorcerer is the actual rank.

Comment: Your sentence "It is a single one" seems to refer to "First Class", but the question asks whether "Grand Sorcerer" applies to "Order of Merlin" as well.

Comment: Thanks,I hadn't realised that I didn't express myself clearly,I will edit it.

Comment: "Grand Sorcerer" is a title distinct from "Order of Merlin": http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Grand_Sorcerer

Comment: Well,I was saying what I thought the sentence meant from a semantic point of view,I am not really a Harry Potter geek,but thank you for your comment :).

Comment: Yeah, this was probably a better fit for scifi.stackexchange.com